# Use Office 365 REST API to manage files in One Drive

Tags: rest, office365, onedrive

I'm developing a system that need manage files in OneDrive for business, but it can't have any human interaction. To do this, I'm following the next link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543

I have no problem in this part, but when I try to do a REST request to the Office 365 API, this answers:

Invalid audience Uri 'MyAppAzureAD'.

Documentation to the Office 365 REST API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/files-rest-operations

I can't find a useful information of the problem.
I'm doing the right process to manage OneDrive files without human interaction?
If the process is the right process, what is the meaning of this error?, what can I do?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No, sorry, but if you find something, please, publish it like a response, we are making a lot of thing manually that we could change if we have this resolve, thanks :)